# Hide Delphi 7 COM commands from IDE's like Visual Studio?

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-7

Our company has a big bit of software that has a lot of really useful COM commands.  We have a good solid basic set that allow you do essentially bypass the GUI and get the information you want, but we also have a few that have been added for specific customers.

Ideally, we'd want to "hide" these specific COM commands to the regular user when our .exe is imported into things like Visual Studio.  So although they'd be active, in theory the only people who could use them are the people who have been explicitly told about them.  This would negate a lot of the issues we have with customers using functionality that wasn't really designed to be used by them, and of course would mean not having to support multiple installers.

Comment: Pretty hard to do this. You could ship the .exe with a type library that had erroneous definitions for the methods that you wished to hide. Then you could ship different type libraries for the special customers who had access to the good stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split the type library into a standard and a special one. Whilst the special implementation is still available in the COM server, it can only be used by someone who knows the IIDs and the interface descriptions. If you make the special interfaces inherit from the standard ones, your special customers just have to get access to the special interfaces to get the full functionality.

Comment: Do you know of any resources / code samples showing how to split up the type library as you've suggested?

Comment: Didn't work with D7 for a very long time, but I'm afraid you cannot use the wizards and have to do it manually. You need to create a new type library, but don't add the {$R clause to your project. Otherwise the special type library would be visible to all. Declare the special interfaces with its methods in there. Then add those interfaces to the implementing classes. The implementations should already be available.